# Откат сообщения к предыдущей версии

Tags: обсуждение, правки, откат-правок

В [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/970311/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-vector) вопросе, автор поменял свой изначальный (нерабочий) код на рабочий, после того, как получил ответ. Т. е. теперь невозможно понять, в чем проблема, не посмотрев на предыдущую версию сообщения.

Я [предложил правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/357654), которую отклонили. Думаю, нужно все-таки откатить сообщение к предыдущей версии.

Comment: откатил к первой версии

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В таких случаях надо ставить тревогу для привлечения внимания модератора. Хотя вполне может быть, что автор просто не очень знаком с механикой SO и откат на предыдущую ревизию смог бы сделать сам по просьбе. Так же откат может сделать любой другой участник с репутацией 2к+. В частности, кто-то из ответивших. Публиковать по каждому подобному случаю вопрос на Мете мне кажется избыточным. С отклонившими предложенную правку следует провести разъяснительную беседу, ну а вам рекомендация - при предложении правки писать более очевидный комментарий. Собственно без него трудно быстро понять в чем же её необходимость.

Comment: Зачем с отклонившими проводить разъяснительную беседу? Вполне оправданое отклонение. Если нельзя до 2к+ откатывать, то и не следует проводить откат вручную, черевато ошибками.

Comment: @0xdb достаточно просто скопировать сырой текст ревизии и предложить его на рассмотрение, чтобы не было ошибок. Вероятно, так и было сделано. В принципе, без контекста, то есть полноценного описания правки я бы, возможно, тоже отклонил, ну, или прошел мимо, так как суть правки сразу не очевидна без подглядывания в ответы. Так что про разъяснительную беседу можно немного сбавить обороты :)